# VueJS How to filter search within paginated list

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

In my `vue`-application I have added some filter search, but since I've added pagination I can only search on the first page and not the entire pages. Here is what I got so far:

Laravel API endpoint:

```
public function read(Request $request){

  $albums = Album::orderBy('artist', 'asc')->paginate(10);

  return response()->json(['albums' => $albums]);

}
```

My Vue component (template):

```
<input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search..." />

<ul>
   <li v-for="(record, idx) in albums" :key="idx">
     <div class="album">
        <div class="album__details">
            <span
                >{{ record.artist }} - {{ record.album }}</span
            >
        </div>
        <div class="album__cta">
            <div class="btn-wrapper">
                <button @click="editAlbum(record)">
                    <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-wrapper">
                <button @click="deleteAlbum(record.id)">
                    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<pagination :data="records" @pagination-change-page="getResults"></pagination>
```

the JS:

```
data(){
    return {
       search: "",
       records: {}
    }
},
computed: {
    albums() {
     const search = this.search.toLowerCase().trim();

     if (search) {
        return this.$store.getters["albums/albums"].filter(album => {
            return (
                album.artist
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
                album.album
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
            );
        });
     } else {
        return _.orderBy(
            this.$store.getters["albums/albums"],
            "artist"
        ).slice(0, 10);
     }
  }
},
methods: {
    getResults(page) {
        if (typeof page === "undefined") {
            page = 1;
        }

        this.$store
            .dispatch("albums/read", { page: page })
            .then(response => {
                this.records = response.albums;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("error: ", error);
            });
    }
 },
mounted(){
   this.getResults();
}
```

The Store:

```
state:{
   albums: []
},
getters: {
   albums(state){
     return state.albums;
 }
},
mutations: {
    albums(state, data) {
        state.albums = data;
    }
},
actions: {
    read(context, data) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios({
                url: "/api/albums?page=" + data.page,
                method: "GET"
            })
                .then(response => {
                    const data =
                        response.data != undefined ? response.data : {};
                    context.commit("albums", data.albums.data);
                    resolve(data);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    reject(error);
                });
        });
    },
}
```

So, obviously, the API-endpoint always returns 10 and when I for example try to search for a entry number 14 it returns an empty result. How can I make this work?

Please help.

Comment: I don't know Lavarel, but I guess the problem is from your Lavarel API. You call `paginate(10)` to set the page size to 10, I guess. However, I don't see any code saying which page you want to get, or maybe how many results should be skipped from the beginning.

Comment: Since your pagination is handled on the server, you may need to create a separate server endpoint to handle running a query for filtering.  Then you could paginate those results.